# How to get Google Adwords ad cost over time with PHP?

Tags: php, google-ads-api

So I have successfully established an ouath connection with Google Adwords, but I fail to realize how a request should look like in order to get the ad cost over time. What parameters should I use? 
I was hoping to find a more simple solution, like the api calls made to Google Analytics:

```
   public function getAudienceMetricsAll($google_analytics_account_id)
    {
        $curl = new Curl("https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/data/ga");
        $curl->setParams([
            "ids"         => "ga:" . $google_analytics_account_id,
            "dimensions"  => "ga:date",
            "metrics"     => "ga:users,ga:newUsers,ga:percentNewSessions,ga:sessions,ga:bounces,ga:bounceRate,ga:avgSessionDuration,ga:goalStartsAll,ga:pageviews,ga:pageViewsPerSession",
            "start-date"  => "730daysAgo",
            "end-date"    => "today",
            "max-results" => 10000
        ]);
        $curl->setHeaders([
            "Authorization" => "Bearer " . @$this->aim_account->settings["credentials"]["access_token"]
        ]);

        $data = $curl->sendRequest("json");

        return $data;
    }
```

I mean, just the url and params I need to send in the body of the request. But I don't seem to be able to find such information.

Thank you for your time! Any help is welcomed!

Comment: With which language?

Comment: PHP is the one I need

Comment: You can use php client library to select `Cost`,`AccountCurrencyCode` & `Date` field using `AWQL` from it & download `ADGROUP_PERFORMANCE_REPORT` and then sum the cost column of that `CSV` to get real Adword cost. See report download example on php client library of Adword API on github here https://github.com/googleads/googleads-php-lib/blob/master/examples/AdWords/v201607/Reporting/DownloadCriteriaReportWithAwql.php

Comment: Adwords has a number of reports which you can call and customize which fields and date range you want. https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/appendix/reports

Comment: You can use the PHP library from GitHub https://github.com/googleads/googleads-php-lib

Comment: Also check out https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/guides/start

Comment: I would like not to use a library if possible. Is there any api I can call and parameters for it?